# Download .doc file from angular

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to create a download link upon button click that downloads doc file. The file gets downloaded successfully but the content inside is something else which is '[object Object]'. The file path is in my webroot and I'm accessing the file like this:

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DownloadController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public DownloadController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Image\\CV.doc");
            using MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memorystream);
            }
            memorystream.Position = 0;
            return File(memorystream, "application/msword", "CV.doc");
        }
    }
```

my Shared service.ts. I've changed the observe to 'body' as well.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  cvFilePathURL = "https://localhost:44346/api/Download";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getCV(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.cvFilePathURL, {
      observe: 'response',
      responseType: 'text'
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my componenet.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/shared.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {
  constructor(private service: SharedService) { }
  isExpanded = false;

  collapse() {
    this.isExpanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }
  public Download(): void {
    this.service.getCV().subscribe((data) => {
      var newBlob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/msword" });
      //For Internet Explorer
      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        return window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
      }
       //For other browsers: 
       //Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
      const mainData = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = mainData;
      link.download = "CV.doc";
      link.click();;
    });
  }
}
```

target framework - asp.net core 3.1
Angular Cli - 11.0.6
Update:
So I've managed to download file which has actual contents other than [objects Objects]. However, The file is filled with special characters and is 206 pages long. Original document is only 2 pages long.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some changes you might have to do inside your code or you can check my code what I am going to provide below.
**YOU CONTROLLER**

```
   [HttpPost]
    [Route("get-download-file")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDownloadFile(dynamic data)
    {
        // var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Documents/" + (string)data.fileName);
        var localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath((string)data.mappingPath);
        string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(localFilePath));

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(localFilePath))
            {
                //if file not found than return response as resource not present 
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
            }
            else
            {
                //if file present than read file 
                var fStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                //compose response and include file as content in it
                response = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StreamContent(fStream)
                };
                //set content header of reponse as file attached in reponse
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(fStream.Name)
                };
                //set the content header content type as application/octet-stream as it returning file as reponse 
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return response;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

***In your Service(Angular) add that httpPostMethod:***

```
public httpPostFile(url: string, body: any): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Blob>(this.baseUri + url, body, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleClientError)
        );
}
```

**Finally, you have to call that method from angular. Using code below->**

```
         let tempBlob: any;
          let contentFileType= 'txt'; //you can make that file type dynamic using some addional code.
                    const data = {
                        fileName: this.fileName,
                        mappingPath: '~/Documents/' + this.fileName
                    };
                    this.apiService.httpPostFile('download/get-download-file/', data)
                        .subscribe(fileData => {

                            tempBlob = new Blob([fileData], { type: contentFileType });
                        },
                            (error) => {
                                
                            }, () => {

                               
                                const blob: Blob = new Blob(tempBlob, { type: contentFileType });
                               
                                const fileName: string = this.filedlName;
                                const objectUrl: string = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                const a: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement('a') as HTMLAnchorElement;

                                a.href = objectUrl;
                                a.download = fileName;
                                document.body.appendChild(a);
                                a.click();

                                document.body.removeChild(a);
                                URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
                            });
```

**Note:** There can be more efficient way to download a file in angular and ASP MVC Web API. But this way it worked for me. you can try it. If you find any difficulties than feel free to ask. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Linker-SJNF. Sorry for reaching out this late. I've been trying your code and researching the bits I didn't understand and I've also tried by making some changes on it but It still doesn't work for me. It's either the same or ```{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"Key":"Content-Disposition","Value":["attachment; filename=CV.doc"]},{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/msword"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"trailingHeaders":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}```